# How are atomic operations are a dynamic language feature?

Tags: c#, dynamic-typing, static-typing

I was told that atomic operations are a dynamic language feature. I was too afraid to ask in that context what this actually means because I didn't want my coworkers to think I'm stupid. But I actually don't really understand this statement.

My understanding of the term "atomic operations" is any operation that is either wholly executed or wholly not executed; you will definitely never be halfway through the operation when the thread context switches.

What does this have to do with dynamic vs static typing?

Comment: Who told you, and in what context?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion here. A *dynamic type system* performs type checks at run time. A *dynamic language* generates or compiles code at run time. An *atomic operation* is an operation that can't be interrupted and therefore appears instantaneous to the rest of the system. These three features are *completely unrelated* and can be combined freely in the design of a programming language.

Comment: The context of the discussion was over drinks after a formal debate with a topic of "Static typing is better than dynamic typing." The argument that was being made by the person who said this is that even in the context of a language that is predominantly a statically typed language, there are dynamic features (such as reflection in c#). They made the claim that support for atomic operations is a dynamic feature.

Comment: If your co worker thinks you are stupid, hes living proof that they can always make a bigger idiot.  A valuable lesson here is people are not always as skilled as they would like to think - and in my experience the lower the skills the more talk.

Comment: @mattnz What you're talking about is called the [Dunning-Kruger effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning_Kruger) and it is very real.

Comment: @Doval You think you're smart enough to post links? :-)

Comment: I is smart enough [to post links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)

Comment: @Kelsie "_They made the claim that support for atomic operations is a dynamic feature._"  They were wrong.  And I offer exactly as much support for my assertion as they did for theirs :-)

Comment: @Ross, I don't know if you actually believe that or if you are solely proving a point. Three different people vocally agreed when this person made the point, so I suspect that there might be somebody out there who actually knows what this is about.

Comment: @Kelsie Nope, I really mean it, and I've got 35 years professional coding experience behind me.  The first language I ever used atomic operations in was IBM 360 assembler, and I've used them in many non-dynamic languages in that time.

Answer (score 9):

> I was too afraid to ask in that context what this actually means because I didn't want my coworkers to think I'm stupid.

Actually, I think that asking questions is smart. It's how you learn things that you don't know. And in larger groups, it's likely that other people don't know it either, they're just afraid to ask too.

> My understanding of the term "atomic operations" is any operation that is either wholly executed or wholly not executed …

Yes, but that's only part of it. Another important part is that the operation appears to execute instantaneously, that is, you can never observe it in half-completed state. (Though the following part of the sentence indicates that that's what you meant.)

> … such as in C# with the volatile keyword when setting or getting the value of a primitive, you will definitely never be halfway through getting or setting a volatile primitive when the thread context switches.

That's not what `volatile` in C# is about. Setting the value of small primitive types (like `int`, `char` or reference, but *not* `long` or `double`) is *always* guaranteed to be atomic (see §5.5 Atomicity of variable references of the C# spec).

What `volatile` is about is the order of accessing the fields (§10.5.3 Volatile fields of the spec). Normally, if you write something like:

```
this.value = 42;
this.valueIsSet = true;
```

and then observe it from another thread, then you could see `valueIsSet` to be already `true` and `value` to be still `0`, due to compiler and processor optimizations that reorder instructions. With `volatile`, such reordering is forbidden.

This also guarantees that the field is read every time, without `volatile` a loop like

```
while (this.shouldRun)
{
    // whatever; does not set this.shouldRun
}
```

might be compiled as:

```
if (this.shouldRun)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // whatever; does not set this.shouldRun
    }
}
```

In any case, using `volatile` correctly is hard and you should avoid it unless you really need it for performance reasons. Most of the time, using locks and thread-safe library types is enough.

> What does this have to do with dynamic vs static typing?

No idea. There certainly are non-trivial atomic operations in .Net (like those in the `Interlocked` class).

The only thing I can think of is that some languages can use [user-mode threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) instead of native threads, and thus have more control over what operations are executed atomically, because it's the language runtime that decides when to switch threads. But that has nothing to do with dynamic or static typing. (And I have no idea if there are languages that actually take advantage of that.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for clarifying my misunderstanding of volatile in c#.

Comment: @Kelsie: Your misunderstanding is very common. You might want to read my series of articles on this subject. It begins here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/26/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-one.aspx, then http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-two.aspx, then http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx.